# MDT Install Error

Tags: automated-install, mdt

I have recently imaged a machine, and I have got this error when it gets to the installing OS stage -

```
windows could not display the images available for installation
```

I've never come across this error before, i've imaged lots of machines in the past but never hit this before, and i cant find much information about it

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild your task task sequence. 95% of the strange errors in task sequences are caused by problems w/ the XML file itself, re-creating a new task sequence is easy and solves many of these strange issues. Check the Task Sequence Log File and the BDD.log file as well. If your share is not configured to log, make sure you're using regular logs and  dynamic logs as well, both come in handy, and one has far more useful information. Set these logs in your CS .ini file:

SLShare=\SERVERNAME\DeploymentShare$\Logs\%SERIALNUMBER%
SLShareDynamicLogging=\SERVERNAME\DeploymentShare$\Logs\%SERIALNUMBER%

Here's a great MDT troubleshooting guide in PDF from technet:

http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-03-51-93-68/Troubleshooting-Windows-Deployments-2012_2D00_09_2D00_11.pdf